# NInject Extension Factory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, factory

After reading the new documentation on **NInject v3** and how to use the *Factory Extension*, apparently I still don't get it fully since my code throws exceptions all over the place...

I get this Exception, i could paste the whole thing if people would like that but i'll try and keep it short for now.

> Error activating IDeployEntityContainer No matching bindings are available,
>       and the type is not self-bindable.

Here is my code...
The Ninject Bind Module class

```
class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        ...
        Bind<IDeployEntityFactory>().ToFactory();
        Bind<IDeployEntityContainer>().To<DeployEntityContainer>();
        ...
    }
}
```

The class which uses the factory

```
class DeployController : IDeployController {

    private readonly IDeployEntityFactory _entityFactory;

    public DeployController(..., IDeployEntityFactory entityFactory) {
        ...
    }

    public void Execute() {
       ...
       //I get the Exception on this line...
       _entityFactory.GetDeployEntity<IDeployEntityContainer>();
       ...
    }
}
```

Factory Interface

```
public interface IDeployEntityFactory
{
    T GetDeployEntity<T>();
}
```

The Factory Implementation

```
public class DeployEntityFactory : IDeployEntityFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;

    public DeployEntityFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public T GetDeployEntity<T>()
    {
        return _resolutionRoot.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

> Behind the scenes Ninject will create a proxy that implements the
>   specified factory interface and intercept all methods so that the
>   proxy behaves like...

I understand that I don't have to actually create the implementation my self if i don't need to do something special/custom in the creation of objects inside the factory.

Source: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/

**EDIT1:**

Just to make sure i leave you with every bit of information you need to see the problem, i'm adding the DeployEntityContainer class/Interface

```
public abstract class DeployEntityBase : IDeployEntity
{
    ...
    protected readonly IDeployEntityFactory _entityFactory;

    protected DeployEntityBase(..., IDeployEntityFactory entityFactory)
    {
        ...
        _entityFactory = entityFactory;
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public class DeployEntityContainer : DeployEntityBase, IDeployEntityContainer
{
    ...
    public DeployEntityContainer(..., IDeployEntityFactory entityFactory)
        : base(..., entityFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: see if this question helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074848/ninject-2-1-activationexception-error-activating-string

Comment: Maybe i'm overlooking something crucial, but i can't seem to find the solution to my problem in that post, thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Does it work when the factory doesnt use generics?

Comment: actually i haven't tried that... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just changing the bindings to normal bindings,

```
Bind<IMyFactory>().To<MyFactory>().InSingletonScope();
```

and it worked! My first thought was lol, but it makes sense as well.

With the `ToFactory()` binding it never ever used my implementation of the factory, it just generated one from the defined interface.

Now it uses my implementation. The factory is changed a bit: From newing up the kernel in the factory or injecting it in the constructor, now I inject `IResolutionRoot` which `Get<T>();` my objects.

Here is the new code just for clarification.

```
class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        ...
        Bind<IDeployEntityFactory>().To<DeployEntityfactory>().InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IDeployEntityContainer>().To<DeployEntityContainer>();
        ...
    }
}

public class DeployEntityFactory : IDeployEntityFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;
    ...
    public DeployEntityFactory(..., IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        ...
        _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public T GetDeployEntity<T>()
    {
        return _resolutionRoot.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

If this is not the right way to do it, I hope somebody can shed light on it and notify me with the right way... I imagine @remogloor would know such a thing. :)