# How do I bind IFactory to a concrete implementation?

Tags: c#, ninject

I need a factory class to do a bit of work before it can return an instance, so I have a factory method like this:

```
public Foo Create(string bar, IEnumerable<SomeMetaData> metaData)
{
    var meta = new ObservableCollection<AnotherType>(
                        metaData.Select(e => new AnotherType { ... }).ToList());

    return Create(new ConstructorArgument("bar", bar),
                  new ConstructorArgument("metaData", meta));
}
```

The concrete factory class derives from a base factory which spares me the actual wiring, in case you wondered where the `IResolutionRoot` had gone:

```
public abstract class FactoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot;
    protected FactoryBase(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        _resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    protected T Create(params IParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return _resolutionRoot.Get<T>(parameters);
    }
}
```

(I have a question on CodeReview about this abstract class if anyone wants to comment about it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25038/are-there-side-effects-to-having-a-generic-ninject-factory)

The problem is that in the NinjectModule, I can't figure out how to tell Ninject to use that specific concrete `FooFactory` class:

```
Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory(); // uses an abstract factory that doesn't do what I need
Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory<FooFactory>(); // doesn't build
```

I believe what I need is something like this:

```
Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory<FooFactory>(Func<FooFactoryInstanceProvider>);
```

What do I need to do in order to provide this `InstanceProvider`?
Possibly it's just my misunderstanding of `Func<T>` but I find http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/31/ninject-extensions-factory-introduction/ is too vague about this.

I came up with this:

```
public class FooFactoryInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override Type GetType(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        return typeof(FooFactory);
    }
}
```

So far so good? What's the next step?

Comment: Also I don't feel the accepted answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207681/ninject-extension-factory?rq=1 is the right thing to do here - I don't want `.InSingletonScope`... or do I?

Comment: BTW Pretty much all of Remo's posts like the one you cite become wiki articles and get updated and improved from there -worth trying to find the equivalent article just in case it has an update

Comment: @RubenBartelink thanks, that's good to know - now I have https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki and https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki in my Chrome favorite bar, and something tells me they're there to stay!

Comment: Dont be afraid to edit them or add examples too - every little refinement will help someone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've gone to the effort to make your own `FooFactory` implementation, why not just bind to it in the *non-factory* way:

Instead of:

```cs
Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory<FooFactory>();
```

Use:

```cs
Bind<IFooFactory>().To<FooFactory>();
```

If you are creating your own factory implementations, what drives your need to use the `ToFactory()` method from the Ninject Factory Extensions, exactly?

**EDIT 1 - Using the factory extensions with custom instance provider**

this way, you put the logic for resolving the `Foo` you want in the custom instance provider. If you can get the logic to match the name of a `Foo` implementation, you're in business.

```cs
public class BlueFiftyTwoFoo : Foo { }

Bind<IFooFactory>().ToFactory(() => new FooFactoryInstanceProvider());
```

and the custom instance provider figures out the name of the `Foo` implementation you want based on your IFooFactory's `Create() method arguments like this:

```cs
public class FooFactoryInstanceProvider : StandardInstanceProvider
{
    protected override string GetName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        // harvest the 1st factory method arg, cast as appropriate 
        string fooParamOne = (string)arguments[0];  // ex. "Blue"

        // harvest the 2nd factory method arg, cast as appropriate 
        string fooParamTwo = (string)arguments[1];  // ex. "FiftyTwo"

        // manipulate the params to come up with the **Name** of the 
        //  IFoo implementation you want
        var fooName = GetFooName(fooParamOne, fooParamTwo);

        return fooName; // ex. "BlueFiftyTwoFoo"
    }

    protected override ConstructorArgument[] GetConstructorArguments(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] arguments)
    {
        // skip the number of params you're using above to come up with the implementation name
        return base.GetConstructorArguments(methodInfo, arguments).Skip(2).ToArray();
    }

    private string GetFooName(string fooParamOne, string fooParamTwo)
    {
        // do that voodoo that you do
        return fooParamOne + fooParamTwo + "Foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my first time using Ninject, reading through the documentation I was left with the impression that I needed the Factory Extensions to achieve this! Your answer makes total sense (looks like the tree was hiding the forest, I should have tried this!), it *seems* to be working but now I'm having an ActivationException with binding another dependency (which deserves its own question I guess). As soon as I resolve this ActivationException I'll be able to confirm your answer works, and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely - I'm very interested in working with Ninject, and have some advanced scenarios using the Factories extensions as well as some others (Conventions extension is very cool) in my own projects. Put a comment with your new question link if you post one, and I'm happy to help out.

Comment: I haven't completely solved my issues but the ActivationException I'm getting is now deep enough into the activation path to tell me the factory binding does work; I'll notify you if I end up posting another question, thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with an option for using the `ToFactory()` method and a custom instance provider.  I think you're barking up the wrong tree overriding the `GetType()` method with your custom instance provider.  I'm sure there's a reason to do it, but most examples I see override the two methods I did in my implementation.  I think it might work for your scenario, too.  I'm guessing that's where you might have had activation problems?

Comment: Awesome, I wish I could upvote your answer again! I ended up resolving the activation issues; I was double-binding one of the views and had to use `.WhenInjectedInto<T>()` and `.WithConstructorArgument()` to bind another dependency. As for overriding `GetType()`, it was merely just a wild guess, I had no clue how to use any of the functions. `GetType()` is inherited from `System.Object`, overriding it was plain useless at best, confusing and eventually a nice bug at worst.

Comment: I've been experimenting a lot with Ninject lately, and asking a lot of questions here about it here too.  I can't get anyone to explicitly confirm yet, my understanding that the `ToFactory` method and the factory extension are convenient wrappers to support *named binding*, where one way or another, the *name* of the type to be bound is determined, so ultimately something somewhere is manipulating or building a string.  Definitely spend some time in the source code on GitHub looking at the tests.  I learned as much from that than the wiki they have.